# preserving the order in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, case

I have a SQL query like this:

```
SELECT * from Ask where Number IN 1,3,2
```

This returns the results as 1,2,3 as opposed to 1,3,2.

Is there a way to force the matching recordset to preserve the query order?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `case` expression in the `order by` clause:

```
select * 
from ask 
where num in (1,3,2)
order by case num
    when 1 then 1
    when 3 then 2
    when 2 then 3
end
```

Depending on your database, syntactical shortcuts may be available.

Oracle has `decode()`:

```
order by decode(num, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3)
```

MySQL has `field()`:

```
order by field(num, 1, 3, 2)
```

Side note: `num` is a language keyword in many databases. I renamed it to `num` in the query.

Comment: Thanks but I got hit but this: SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]'field' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: That's because SQLSERVER does not have what mySQL does. Do you happen to know the equivalent of "field" in mssql server by any chance GMB?

Comment: @HalukKaramete: I did mention that `field()` is MySQL syntax. Obviously you are not  running MySQL, but SQL Server. Use the first query in the answer: `case` is standard SQL, that pretty much all databases support (including SQL Server).